# Word VBA Save As Dialog with custom filter?

Tags: vba, filter, ms-word, dialog, save-as

Is there a way (code) for "Save As" dialog in Word VBA with customer filters? For example: ".ttt"

Comment: do you want to show dialog box for 'save as' with predefined file type? but it won't convert file to '.psd' as this type is not supported by word...

Comment: The .psd file format was an example to show about custom filters. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you probably want to use the `Application.FileDialog` as this allows custom file filters.  As KazJaw points out you can't save a Photoshop file in Word so I assume its to allow some other manipulation of a `psd` file.

The following shows you how to use it (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa219843%28office.11%29.aspx).  Note this will allow the user to select multiple files though.

```
Sub CustomFilter()
    'Declare a variable for the FileDialog object and one for the selectedItems
    Dim fd As FileDialog, vSelectedItem As Variant

    'Create a FileDialog object as a File Picker dialog box.
    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

    'With the FileDialog
    With fd
        .Filters.Clear                              'Clear current filters
        .Filters.Add "Photoshop Files", "*.psd", 1  'Add a filter that has Photoshop Files.

        If .Show = -1 Then
            'Step through each String in the FileDialogSelectedItems collection.
            For Each vSelectedItem In .SelectedItems
                'Do whatever you want here
            Next vSelectedItem
        Else
            'The user pressed Cancel.
        End If
    End With

    Set fd = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: The .psd file format was an example to show about custom filters. Furthermore, will this work for SAVE AS dialogs?

Comment: You cannot use custom filters with the SaveAs dialog (outside of the default Word file types), if you want to use custom filters (such as .psd or .ttt) you must use the FileDialog box.  Why do you need to use SaveAs? (You can use the FileDialog box to get the filename and then save.)

Comment: However, the file have to exists in order to use FileDialog?

Comment: No not at all. If the file does not exist then the user will press cancel and the `.Show` value will equal `0` (From memory I'm not at a computer at the moment), you can then use code to handle that.